# T-SQL UPDATE query to fill NULL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Quotes.quoteID, Orders.orderID, Orders.invoiceID, 
    Quotes.parentOrderID AS QuoteParent, Orders.parentOrderID AS OrderParent
FROM 
    Quotes 
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON Quotes.orderID = Orders.orderID
```

I need to fill all the `OrderParent` columns with valid (not null) values in `QuoteParent` column.

How do I write the `UPDATE` query?

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#UpdateExamples) in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), including one on [Using the WHERE clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-the-where-clause). What about those didn't you understand? What was *your* attempt? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE o
SET parentOrderID = q.parentOrderID
FROM dbo.Orders o
INNER JOIN Quotes q ON o.OrdersID = q.OrderID
WHERE o.parentOrderID IS NULL
  AND q.parentOrderID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: didnt know how to message you really. I am in as ecurity role and have a question which I cant just post. Are you happy for us to chat before I have the question posted? Just asking